# Plone: Dexterity Model driven content type with collective.z3cform.datagridfield - nesting an xml model in an xml model

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'd like to create a content type that uses collective.z3cform.datagridfield. I have been trying to follow the example mentioned in this presentation:
http://glicksoftware.com/presentations/dexterity-in-the-wild

The example demonstrates referencing a second schema from the main schema. This is my attempt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<model xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/schema"
       xmlns:form="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/form">
<field name="telephone" type="zope.schema.List"
    form:widget="collective.z3cform.datagridfield.DataGridFieldFactory">

      <title>Telephone</title>
      <description>Enter telephone numbers here</description>
      <max_length>10</max_length>
      <min_length>2</min_length>
      <missing_value/>
      <readonly>False</readonly>
      <required>False</required>

      <value_type type="collective.z3cform.datagridfield.DictRow">
        <title>Number</title>
        <schema>mypackage.mytype.IPhoneSchema</schema>
      </value_type>
    </field>
</schema>
</model>
```

I define my second schema in **mypackage/mytype.py** to look like this:

```
from plone.supermodel import model

class IPhoneSchema(model.Schema):
    """Schema for dict rows used in DataGridFields
    name is the 'real'  name
    token is the token used in the vocabularies
    """
#
    model.load("models/phone.xml")
```

And then in **models/phone.xml** I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<model xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/schema"
       xmlns:form="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/form">

    <schema>
         <field name="number" type="zope.schema.TextLine"> 
            <description/> 
            <required>False</required> 
            <title>Number</title> 
        </field> 
    </schema>
</model>
```

When I start Plone I get the following error:

```
 SupermodelParseError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mytype'
      <schema>mypackage.mytype.IPhoneSchema</schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively, both model xml files were defined in the mytype.py file. This caused an issue at runtime where mytype.py cannot call ... mytype.IPhoneSchema.

The solution was to create a **phoneschema.py** file independent of mytype.py with the following content:

> from plone.supermodel import model
>
> class IPhoneSchema(model.Schema):
>
> ```
>    """Schema for dict rows used in DataGridFields
>    they are used for individual phone numbers
>    """
>
>    model.load("models/phone.xml")
> ```

Instead of calling mytype.IPhoneSchema, we can now call **phoneschema.IPhoneSchema**. I can include the phone schema in models/**mytype.xml** (see the example below).

> ...
>
> ```
>   <title>Telephone</title>
>   <description>Enter telephone numbers here</description>
>   <max_length>10</max_length>
>   <min_length>2</min_length>
>   <missing_value/>
>   <readonly>False</readonly>
>   <required>False</required>
>
>   <value_type type="collective.z3cform.datagridfield.DictRow">
>     <title>Number</title>
>     <schema>mypackage.mytype.IPhoneSchema</schema>
>   </value_type>
> </field>
> ```
>
> ...

Here's a diagram of the relationship, phoneschema.py 'loads' phone.xml:

[image: phoneschema.py loads phone.xml]

For the sake of reference, the file tree of my product now would look something like this (I've put a star next to the key file in this scenario **phoneschema.py** which references the second model file):

```
...
├── __init__.py
├── configure.zcml
├── mytype.py
├── mytype_templates
│   └── view.pt
├── models
│   ├── mytype.xml
│   └── phone.xml
├── *phoneschema.py
...
```